# Get next available from DB according to an ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql

Exampe of the table

[image]

Now to what i'm trying to accomplish.
I want to be able to get the next `target_name` AFTER the one i have looked but with the order by that is in the picture `target_name DESC`.

Say i give an input of `02A` it should return `02B`, if input is `02D` it should go `20A`.
In most cases it'll be `01A,01B,01C,01D,02A,02B etc etc`. 
I could go ahead and check the next after using php but in some rare cases i'll spam the DB with queries and i was hoping i could avoid that.

Is there anyway i could `SELECT` that with a query

Comment: Sth. like `SELECT MIN(target_name) FROM table WHERE target_name > '02A'`?

Comment: didn't need the MIN but worked yeah. If you may answer so that i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(target_name) FROM table WHERE target_name > '02A'
```

The `MIN(target_name)` makes the query only return the next bigger value. leaving it away makes it return all, you schould probably add a proper `group by` if you do that.